# How to find all objects of specific type in folders?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say, I have a folders structure with files inside. In some files, objects of a specific type can be found. I want to initiate them dynamically (I know each instance of that type has a specific method). But I don't know how I would implement it. I think the pseudocode could be something like that:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_folder):
    for f in files:
        if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == '.py':
            get_fully_name_of_the_file # like app.modules.amazon
            from from_fully_name import that_instance
            that_instance.my_method()
```

Comment: You seem to know what you're doing.  Where are you stuck?  Getting the fully-qualified path and/or the simple file name (no directories) are both documented methods in the `os` package.  A file name may include periods anywhere, not only before the extension -- you likely want `splitext(f)[-1]`, or a slice from a right-side search: `f.rindex('.'):`

Comment: I'm stuck starting from get_fully_name_of_the_file because I don't really know how to implement it with Python.

Comment: As I said, it's in the `os` documentation for file names -- path, base name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
all_types=[]
for f in glob.glob("root_folder"):
    all_types.append[f[f.rindex("."):]]
print(all_types)
```